# Tensorflow frozen model only contains output placeholder variable

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to freeze a pre-trained model to then convert it in TF Lite and deploy it into an Android device.

By inspecting the resulting .pb file with xxd I see that it only contains the placeholder output variable. The size of the .pb is a few Bytes.

Why all the graph and variables are not included in the model?

I used the code below derived from https://github.com/sankit1/cv-tricks.com/tree/master/Tensorflow-tutorials/freeze_model_and_deploy. It works fine with other models but not with mine.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_util
import os,sys

path = './model-gaze/'
output_node_names = "pos"
model_name = 'model-23'

saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(path+model_name+'.meta', clear_devices=True)

graph = tf.get_default_graph()
input_graph_def = graph.as_graph_def()
sess = tf.Session()
saver.restore(sess, path+model_name)
output_graph_def = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
            sess, # The session is used to retrieve the weights
            input_graph_def, # The graph_def is used to retrieve the nodes 
            output_node_names.split(",") # The output node names are used to select the usefull nodes
) 
output_graph=path+model_name+".pb"
with tf.gfile.GFile(output_graph, "wb") as f:
    f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())

sess.close()
```

I would expect that all the weights and graph data are included inside the .pb  but cannot manage to get them there.

Answer (score 0):

The link which you are following is the right procedure to freeze a tensorflow model.

Freezing a model reduces the size of the model as it only saves the ""output_node_names"" which you give it to store.

Please refer to the below link on the entire process. 
https://cv-tricks.com/how-to/freeze-tensorflow-models/

Here,  can you please elaborate on what ""pos"" is ?

Also, here if you pass the prediction op as that is the required final op for predictions, it should work fine.

And if this does not help, please share your model and the code from where you have saved the model, to further debug the issue.